# Handling tuple data for pathpy visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have the data in `.txt` format separated by spaces and line breaks. Here is some of them.

```
1 2 1082040961
3 4 1082155839
5 2 1082414391
6 7 1082439619
8 7 1082439756
```

This data represents temporal graphs, `G = (u, v, t)`, where `u`, `v`, and `t`  means there is an edge from node `u`  to node `v` with timestamp `t`.

I want to visualize these data using Python's library [`pathpy`](https://github.com/uzhdag/pathpy).
They must be coded like below to add an edge.

```
t.add_edge('1', '2', 1082040961)
t.add_edge('3', '4', 1082155839)
t.add_edge('5', '2', 1082414391)
t.add_edge('6', '7', 1082439619)
t.add_edge('8', '7', 1082439756)
```

But there are a lot of edges in the data. So I need a smart way to handle this. How should I code this tuple transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the dataset in the following way:

```
with open(filename.txt) as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.strip().split()
        t.add_edge(data[0], data[1], int(data[2])
```

Please let me know if this works or if you have any other questions.

Comment: 't.add_edge(data[0], data[1], int(data[2])' Does this part encoding in single quotes for the data in the first and second columns?

Comment: yes, `data[0]`, `data[1]` and `data[2]` are all strings and hence the first two can be passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you need, but there's a `read_file` function in pathpy library. It allows to construct a new `TemporalNetwork` object from a file of similar format to yours. Check this [commit](https://github.com/uzhdag/pathpy/blob/806a97c833be7041fe4fc32e08f91722aad93f00/pathpy/classes/temporal_network.py#L171).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas library also.

```
import pandas as pd

path = r"C:\txt\file\path"

df = pd.read_fwf(path, header=None)
length = len(df.index)

for i in range(length):
    t.add_edge(df[df.columns[0]][i], df[df.columns[1]][i], df[df.columns[2]][i])
```

Comment: Why are you marking the string in ```path``` with an ```r``` prefix? That prefix marks the start of a regular expression.

Comment: To avoid unicode error. For example, my path is ```"C:\Users\berka\Desktop\dene.txt"``` and ```\b``` causes unicode error.

Comment: @accdias - the `r` doesn't mean it's a regular expression, it means it's a raw string, which are often used for regular expressions, but in this case it just saves having to manually escape the `\\` in the path to filename.

Comment: @thesilkworm, Oh! I see. Thanks for the explanation. I always used it thinking it was a marker for a regular expression and now it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This may help too:

```
print [t.add_edge(str(data[0]),str(data[2]),int(data[4:-1])) for data in open("filename.txt") if data.strip().split(" ")]
```